# What is an efficient way to parse a list of strings in Python?

Tags: python

I am writing a script to validate a deb package is installing to a specific folder. I am pretty green and new to python. I had a script that worked with python-apt module that returned a list with file paths of all files in the package. Due to some dependency issues I can no longer use the python-apt module, so instead I am trying to call `dpkg` to collect the information and parse it to a list of file paths. Below is what I am using to get the list of items returned from the `dpkg` command. I need to parse out everything but the right of the last space. What would be the most efficient way to parse this?

```
self.lists = commands.getoutput("dpkg -c "+deb).split('\n')
```

results of this is this list:

```
list: ['drwxr-xr-x ejohnson/ejohnson 0 2012-03-06 15:24 ./', 'drwxr-xr-x ejohnson/ejohnson 0 2012-03-06 15:14 ./opt/', 'drwxr-xr-x ejohnson/ejohnson 0 2012-03-06 15:14 ./opt/usr/', 'drwxr-xr-x ejohnson/ejohnson 0 2012-03-06 15:15 ./opt/usr/apps/', '-r--r--r-- ejohnson/ejohnson 179491 2012-03-06 15:15 ./opt/usr/apps/xbean-spring-2.8.jar', '-rw-r--r-- ejohnson/ejohnson    518 2012-03-06 15:15 ./opt/usr/apps/Hello.class', '-r--r--r-- ejohnson/ejohnson 1901653 2012-03-06 15:15 ./opt/usr/apps/spring-1.2.6.jar']
```

I want to reformat the list so that each item in the list would be the item after the last space for example `['./','./opt/','./opt/usr/','./opt/usr/apps/'...]`

Thanks for looking

Comment: `self.lists = [line.split(' ')[-1] for line in commands.getoutput("dpkg -c "+deb).split('\n')]`. Can be optimized though.

Comment: I suggest using `... [line.split()[-1] ...`.

Answer (score 6):

Simple, just have your list in `l` variable and this code should work for you.

```
[el.split()[-1] for el in l]
```

Comment: Don't suggest that anyone ever create a variable with the name of a built-in unless the intention is explicitly to shadow that built-in.

Comment: Looks like the OP already used that name. Don't hammer zeroos for that.

Comment: @Marcin, good point actually, just changed the name of this variable.

Answer (score 2):

Turn each of the strings into a list by using `split`. Take the last element of each list using relative list indexing.

For extra credit, do it in a one line list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

`str.rpartition` may be more efficient than `str.split`

```
[x.rpartition(" ")[2] for x in your_list]
```

For the sample here, it is more than twice as fast

```
$ python -m timeit -s "L=['drwxr-xr-x ejohnson/ejohnson 0 2012-03-06 15:24 ./', 'drwxr-xr-x ejohnson/ejohnson 0 2012-03-06 15:14 ./opt/', 'drwxr-xr-x ejohnson/ejohnson 0 2012-03-06 15:14 ./opt/usr/', 'drwxr-xr-x ejohnson/ejohnson 0 2012-03-06 15:15 ./opt/usr/apps/', '-r--r--r-- ejohnson/ejohnson 179491 2012-03-06 15:15 ./opt/usr/apps/xbean-spring-2.8.jar', '-rw-r--r-- ejohnson/ejohnson    518 2012-03-06 15:15 ./opt/usr/apps/Hello.class', '-r--r--r-- ejohnson/ejohnson 1901653 2012-03-06 15:15 ./opt/usr/apps/spring-1.2.6.jar']" \
> "[x.split()[-1] for x in L]"
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.2 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s "L=['drwxr-xr-x ejohnson/ejohnson 0 2012-03-06 15:24 ./', 'drwxr-xr-x ejohnson/ejohnson 0 2012-03-06 15:14 ./opt/', 'drwxr-xr-x ejohnson/ejohnson 0 2012-03-06 15:14 ./opt/usr/', 'drwxr-xr-x ejohnson/ejohnson 0 2012-03-06 15:15 ./opt/usr/apps/', '-r--r--r-- ejohnson/ejohnson 179491 2012-03-06 15:15 ./opt/usr/apps/xbean-spring-2.8.jar', '-rw-r--r-- ejohnson/ejohnson    518 2012-03-06 15:15 ./opt/usr/apps/Hello.class', '-r--r--r-- ejohnson/ejohnson 1901653 2012-03-06 15:15 ./opt/usr/apps/spring-1.2.6.jar']" \
> "[x.rpartition(' ')[2] for x in L]"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.55 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s "L=['drwxr-xr-x ejohnson/ejohnson 0 2012-03-06 15:24 ./', 'drwxr-xr-x ejohnson/ejohnson 0 2012-03-06 15:14 ./opt/', 'drwxr-xr-x ejohnson/ejohnson 0 2012-03-06 15:14 ./opt/usr/', 'drwxr-xr-x ejohnson/ejohnson 0 2012-03-06 15:15 ./opt/usr/apps/', '-r--r--r-- ejohnson/ejohnson 179491 2012-03-06 15:15 ./opt/usr/apps/xbean-spring-2.8.jar', '-rw-r--r-- ejohnson/ejohnson    518 2012-03-06 15:15 ./opt/usr/apps/Hello.class', '-r--r--r-- ejohnson/ejohnson 1901653 2012-03-06 15:15 ./opt/usr/apps/spring-1.2.6.jar']" \
> "[x.rsplit(' ',1)[1] for x in L]"
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.5 usec per loop
```

Comment: `x.rsplit(' ',1)[1]` was fastest for me.

Comment: @Steven: You could also use `rsplit(None, 1)[1]` to keep those any-amount-of-space semantics.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski,might depend on the cpu and the version of Python amongst other things. I ran it with Python2.7.2 on a Core2 cpu

Comment: `rpartition` is also fastest with Python2 and Python3 on a pentium G850